# Поиск на Яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-maps-embed

Хочу добавить поиск на Яндекс карту, сделанную в конструкторе карт.
Просто добавить api ключ к коду не помогает.

Comment: Если не работает, значит у вас невалидный ключ или он неправильно прописан в коде ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Чтобы разобраться нужен полный пример подключения с вашим ключом и инфа из Кабинет разработчика по статусу ключа, но такое не стоит выкладывать на SO. Лучше вам написать в техподдержку Яндекса.

Comment: Такая же ситуация, добавил в код ключ и ничего, поиска как не было так и нет, ключ новый, должен быть валидным

Comment: @Николай напишите в техподдержку, ключ активируется до 15 минут, но если 15 минут прошло и не работает, то значит что-то не так с ключом/подключением